# Enabling FTP on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

How do I do that? I don't have a clue where to start?

Comment: To make a note here, Juan was talking about running an FTP server, not a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to Setup an FTP server to host files?

I'd first make sure your ISP doesn't block incoming port 21.

If you can receive incoming connections on port 21, then setup [vsftpd](https://help.ubuntu.com/6.06/ubuntu/serverguide/C/ftp-server.html).

Comment: good ol' google

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to install an FTP server program.  To do this use the "apt-get" command, which must be run as root (so use the "sudo" command).  The syntax is:

```
sudo apt-get install (name of package to install)
```

Right now, on my Mythbuntu system (which is basically Ubuntu with the addition of MythTV packages), the available FTP server packages are:

```
   wzdftpd 0.8.3-6ubuntu1
   wu-ftpd 2.6.2-30ubuntu1
   twoftpd-run 1.21-8
   pure-ftpd-postgresql 1.0.21-11.4ubuntu1
   pure-ftpd-mysql 1.0.21-11.4ubuntu1
   pure-ftpd-ldap 1.0.21-11.4ubuntu1
   pure-ftpd 1.0.21-11.4ubuntu1
   proftpd-basic 1.3.1-17ubuntu1
   muddleftpd 1.3.13.1-4.2
   krb5-ftpd 1.6.dfsg.4~beta1-5ubuntu2
   inetutils-ftpd 2:1.6-1
   heimdal-servers 1.2.dfsg.1-2.1ubuntu1
   ftpd-ssl 0.17.27+0.3-3ubuntu1
   ftpd 0.17-29
   vsftpd 2.0.7-0ubuntu1
```

My suggestion is to go with vsftpd, it seems to be the best in terms of support and security.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using **SFTP** instead due to the lack of security of FTP. If you wish to set up SFTP, just install `openssh-server` and it is done.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you actually sure you want FTP? Are there any reasons you specifically need FTP (such as lame or legacy software)?

The internet recommends that you use SFTP. SFTP travels over SSH, so you probably don't need to install or enable anything else (provided you already have `openssh` installed). SFTP will use the same user accounts and permission settings that you set for regular system (and SSH) users. Also, most of your FTP clients are already SFTP compatible.

If you don't already have SSH installed, just run this in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

And you should be going straight away!